# Hebrew google map

Tags: google-maps

I work with fusion table to integrate with google maps and do so with the google drive environment, the google map is in English, and for my web application i want to work with a hebrew map (a good example:
https://maps.google.com/?hl=iw&ie=UTF8&ll=32.226743,34.747009&spn=2.183969,2.69989&z=9
)

instead an English map.
Also I liked to type locations in Hebrew and the google map returns me the location of that areas on my Hebrew goolge map.

Thank you,

​

Comment: The link does not lead me to any Hebrew maps. What about a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the language, for google-maps via the `hl`-parameter(set it to `he`):

https://maps.google.com/?hl=he&ie=UTF8&ll=32.226743,34.747009&spn=2.183969,2.69989&z=9&output=classic

For implementations using the javascript-API use the `language`-parameter when you include the API